# Get initial value from a JSON and add with other values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sweeping a JSON and grabbing the value of a snack.

```
{
 "lanches": [
        {   
            "id": 1,
            "name": "X-Bacon",
            "ingredients": [
                "Bacon",
                "Hambúrguer",
                "Queijo"
            ],
            "initialValue: 9.00
        }
    ]
    }
```

I need to show it when the system starts .. so far okay.

I have a list of additional items that is another JSON swept.

```
{
"ingredientes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Alface",
            "price": 0.40
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bacon",
            "price": 2.00
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Hambúrguer de carne",
            "price": 3.00
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Ovo",
            "price": 4.00
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Queijo",
            "price": 5.00
        }
    ]
}
```

When you add each item, you need to add up with the initial value. I can add only the added items. I can not add the first value and add it with the items.

Here is where I sweep the JSON to pick up the snacks

```
{this.state.lanches.map(lanche => (
    <div className="item" key={lanche.id}>
        <div className="item__desc--top">
            <h2 className="item__title">{lanche.name}</h2>
            <p className="item__price">{this.state.totalPrice}</p>
        </div>
        <ul className="item__ingredientes">
            {lanche.ingredients.map(ingredientes =>
                <li className="item__ingredientes--itens" key={ingredientes}>
                <span>{ingredientes}</span>
                { this.state.editItem ? <button className="actionRemove"><i className="fa fa-times"></i></button> : null}
                </li>
            )}
        </ul>
            <p className="itens__adicionais">Add Items</p>
            <ul className="itens__adicionais--menu">
                {this.state.ingredientes.map(ingrediente =>
                    <li className="itens__adicionais--item" key={ingrediente.id}>
                    <span>{ingrediente.name}</span>
                    <button className="actionAdd" onClick={((e) => this.handleAdd(e, ingrediente.price, lanche.price))}><i className="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
    </div>
))}
```

And here is the function of summing the value:

```
handleAdd = (e, value_ingrediente) => {
    this.setState(
        {
            totalPrice: this.state.totalPrice + value_ingrediente
        }
    )
  }
```

Comment: And what's the issue ?

Comment: Put "initialValue" in state totalPrice in inital moment. being that this value comes from json

Comment: Do it exactly like you did with the ingrediants : a `handleAdd` function for the `lanches`, and update the state in there.